# Inaccurate y values for simple Matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to create a very simple plot using Matplotlib:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 10000)
y = 3 * x**2 + 1

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

This creates a plot, but when I mouseover various points, the y values displayed seem to be significantly off from what they should be:

x = 0, y = 0.4 instead of 1
[image: x = 0, y = 0.4 instead of 1]

What's going on here?

Comment: The values displayed in the status bars are unrelated to the curve.  They are just the values corresponding to the picture where the mouse is.  Zooming in would give some more detailed values. You could try a library such as [mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to show values on the curve.  Also note that using `np.linspace(...,. ..., 10000)` gives much too many points; something like `500` makes more sense.

Comment: Aha, well that explains it. Thank you!